# How to analyze the Jmeter performance and load testing results?

Tags: load, jmeter, performance-testing

How can I analyze the Jmeter performance and Load testing results? I have read out tutorials but didn't completly understand.
How I know my site is running well over 500 users at same time hitting the URL?
And Also tell me about Graph results?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add an appropriate [Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) to be able to look into results summary.

I would recommend [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) or [Summary Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report) or both. Looking into metrics you'll be able to tell whether you're happy with response times and percentage of errors. Metrics definitions can be found at [The Load Reports](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65153-the-load-reports) page

> **#Samples** is the number of samples with the same label.
>
> **Average** is the average time of a set of results.
>
> **Median** is a number which divides the samples into two equal halves. Half of the samples are smaller than the median, and half are larger. [Some samples may equal the median.] This is a standard statistical measure. The Median is the same as the 50th Percentile.
>
> **90% Line** (90th Percentile) meaning 90% of the samples took no more than this time.
>
> **Min** is the shortest time for the samples with the same label
>
> **Max** is the longest time for the samples with the same label
>
> **Error %** is the percent of requests with errors
>
> **Throughput** is measured in requests per second/minute/hour. The time unit is chosen so that the displayed rate is at least 1.0. When the throughput is saved to a CSV file, it is expressed in requests/second, i.e. 30.0 requests/minute is saved as 0.5.
>
> **Kb/sec** - throughput measured in Kilobytes per second. Time is in milliseconds.

You can also use [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) to build [more informative graphs at the end of test run](http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/automatically-generating-nice-graphs-at-end-of-your-load-test-with-apache-jmeter-and-jmeter-plugins/) or online results analysis service like [Loadosophia.org](http://loadosophia.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Additionally I recommend you to take a look at the Standard and Extra sets of plugins: http://jmeter-plugins.org

In order to analyze server load capabilities I would recommend taking a look at the following listeners:

- Hits per second
- Response Latencies over time
- Response times vs threads
- Transactions per second

These are part of the standard set that you can find in the plugins page.
For easy reading of this graphs (they can became really complex) for each of them go to "Settings" and select "Aggregated display, all Samplers combined", that would allow you to see a very easy to read graphic.

With those graphics you can see how many threads are actually responded by the server, how maximum of threads are able to go through and how many are being queued.

For example, you would be able to see in "Hits per second" that even if you shoot 500 threads to the site that you are actually having maximum 50 hits reaching at some points or things like that.

Take a look at those graphs and I'm sure you'll get a better sense of what's going on with the capacity of your site.

~Nestor

Answer (score -2):

Here answer can be too long if we explain everything as per your question. So I would like to request you to analyze following jmeter tutorial and after that ask if you have question in any particular thing.

[Jmeter tutorial](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html)